# Why SortedSet cannot be deserialized using Blazor webassembly on GitHub Pages?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, github-pages, blazor-webassembly

I tried to make a blazor WebAssembly web site (hosted on Github Pages) that calls a cloud-based API (AWS). It receives a Json-serialized that contains a SortedSet value and deserialized it.

I tried to isolate the issue, and finally got to the minimum code where it can be reproduced, namely it's when you try to deserialize a SortedSet right away.

```
@page "/"

<button onclick="@Deserialize">Deserialize</button>
<br />Message: @message

@code
{
    private string message = "Nothing happened yet";

    private void Deserialize()
    {
        try
        {
            SortedSet<int> sortedSet = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SortedSet<int>>("[1,2,3]");
            message = $"Deserialized SortedSet: {string.Join(",", sortedSet)}";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            message = $"Deserialization ended up in an exception: {e}";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: DeserializeNoConstructor, JsonConstructorAttribute,
  System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1[System.Int32] 
  Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
 ---> System.NotSupportedException: DeserializeNoConstructor,
      JsonConstructorAttribute,
      System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1[System.Int32]
Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack 
at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(ReadStack& , Utf8JsonReader& , NotSupportedException ) 
at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException_DeserializeNoConstructor(Type , Utf8JsonReader& , ReadStack& ) 
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ISetOfTConverter`2[[System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Collections, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].CreateCollection(Utf8JsonReader& , ReadStack& , JsonSerializerOptions ) 
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter`2[[System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Collections, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& , Type , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& , SortedSet`1& ) 
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Collections, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& , Type , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& , SortedSet`1& ) 
at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Collections, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& )
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[SortedSet`1](ReadOnlySpan`1 , JsonTypeInfo , Nullable`1 )
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[SortedSet`1](ReadOnlySpan`1 , JsonTypeInfo ) 
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[SortedSet`1](String , JsonSerializerOptions ) 
at SortedSetDeserializationDemo.Pages.Index.Deserialize()
```

It appears only when hosting on GitHub Pages, and I could not reproduce it when running from Visual Studio.

I have found how it can be fixed. You should serialize any (possibly non-empty) SortedSet *before* deserializing any SortedSet.

Here are some strange details:

1. There is still an error if I add serialization right **after** the deserialization attempt
2. There is no error if I do serialization **in another method, bound to a button. Even if I don't use that button**.
3. No errors when deserializing a List

Some other details that may be relevant:
It does not depend on Release/Debug configuration. I did not test all the possible scenarios, but the ones I tested yield to the same result. It seems that it may be related to JIT.
It can be reproduced in Chrome and Edge.
.NET 6.0 is used (tried both 6.0.10 and 6.0.11)

Here are my questions:

1. What it might be?
2. If it's a bug, is it a .NET/Blazor bug, GitHub Pages bug or browser bug?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, thanks! You seem to be correct. In the two variants (with and without serialization) there is different System.Collections.dll. I replaced only System.Collections.dll and its hash in blazor.boot.json and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

As @HenkHolterman mentioned in the comments, something happens during publish. I tried to compare publish output with and without serialization before deserialization, and it appears that there was different System.Collections.dll. Without s11n it is 8.5KB and with s11n it is 13KB. If I replace only System.Collections.dll to the 13KB version and adjust its hash in blazor.boot.json, everything works correctly. I'm going to create a bug report for dotnet about it.

**Upd:** it appears that it's enough to add a SortedSet constructor.

It explains the odd behavior I observed. It worked with the deserialization before serialization because I had to create a SortedSet to serialize, and I called a SortedSet constructor. When I called Serialize(SortedSet) after deserialization, I used a value that I got from deserialization, so no SortedSet constructor was called from compiled code directly.

In my case serialization in a reflection mode takes place, thus the publishing code is not aware that the SortedSet constructor is used in my application. Thus publishing trims the SortedSet parameterless constructor.

Another wourkaround would be to use [source generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/source-generation-modes?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Apparently, they aren't going to change anything about it, see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/78776 for the details.